# How to lazily load components from another host?

Tags: angular, dynamic-script-loading

How to lazily load components from another host in Angular?

Hello guys. I have a problem with Angular. My web application is deployed on a certain server(e.g. http://www.a.com), and my javascript files are deployed on another server(e.g. http://www.b.com). Now I want to lazily load a component which is deployed on www.b.com, and the request path is always http://www.a.com/component.js, but the correct path is http://www.b.com/component.js. My question is how to deal with it? 
Thanks!

Comment: are you able to create proxy for it (on server side whenever  http://www.a.com/component.js is requested server loads content of http://www.b.com/component.js)?

Comment: @Abhishek you must be joking!!! This is angular built-in lazy loading, what does your link have to do with this?

Comment: @shengliang This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44760962/7986531

Comment: Seems like perfect case for angular Element